# Laravel JWT Auth check if logged in

Tags: laravel, token

i have installed JWT-Auth because i want Token based authentication.

I use Laravel 4 and i don't know how i should check if the Token is valid.

My current way is this:

```
public function index()
{
    if ($user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
        $hunters = Hunter::all();
        return Response::json($hunters);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to check the token in the routes.php.
It would be really hard to implement the method i currently use in all Controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a filter with this code and then you can easily have whatever you need to be authenticated use that filter.

Answer (score 0):

To add it everywhere in your app, use [Route Filters](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters) for Laravel 4 and [Controller Middlewares](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#controller-middleware) for Laravel 5.x.

You can find enough info on how to implement these methods in your app in the docs or just google it.